# Listview, scroll to bottom, weird behaviour with EditText View

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I try to scroll listview to the very bottom and it works this way:

```
listview.setSelection(listview.getCount()-1);
```

(shame on you Google, basic thing scrollToBottom method, and we had to find other way to achieve it..)

But this doesn't work.. when before using it you type some text.. into EditText View. Funny? Not at all.

```
Add element to listview -> scrollToBottom -> you are at the very bottom - works
Add element to listview -> type something in EditView -> scrollToBottom - not works
Add element to listview -> type something in EditView -> click anywhere in screen -> scrollToBottom - works!
```

As we can see problem is strange and weird, I was trying to `[anyView].performClick();` but no luck..

Any idea why typing in EditText makes me thinking about Android Dev Team responsible for listview is so lame? And how we can find workaround for this bug.

Thanks for help! :)

Some code:

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/nativeLog"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:transcriptMode="normal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingTop="0dp"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:paddingLeft="0dp"
     android:paddingRight="0dp"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
     android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
     android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

[...]

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/boxInterfaceEditbox"
     android:scrollHorizontally="false"
     android:inputType="textCapSentences|textLongMessage|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:imeOptions="actionSend"
     android:layout_width ="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5.5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5.5dp"
     android:paddingTop="8.2dp"
     android:paddingBottom="8.2dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:minHeight="@dimen/nav_interface_btn_size"
     android:maxHeight="90dp"
     android:textColor="#bbb"
     android:textSize="15.25dp"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:background="@drawable/nav_boxtextarea"/>
```

And java

```
scrollToBottomRunnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         log.setSelection(log.getCount() -1);
     }
};
```

Comment: @ElSajko Refere here: http://coderzpassion.com/android-custom-listview-with-edittext/ you might get some help

Comment: @JagjitSingh: EditView isn't as item of listview in my case, but I will take a look. Thx.

Comment: I think your edit text gets focus and then your button can not take focus on click so you first touch screen to get focus from edit text

Comment: @bryanc There is no problem with buttons, problem with listview.setSelection (scrollToBottom) not works properly because you typed sth in edittext view.

Comment: Your list will act when you click on **send** key on keypad? Where you call scrollTobottm method?

Comment: @bryanc: I call scrollToBottom (listview.post(runnable)) every time I add something to listview or hide/show Textview-child in ListView-Footer. | 

Send key / or enter wont help, still setSelection doesnt work then. Anything you type or enter / send key makes it broken.

Comment: Call notifyDatasetChanged() after scrollTobottm or adding item

Comment: @bryanc: the good question right now is.. What pressing a, b, c etc what it change that setSelection on listview works different.. EDIT, ok I will try gimme sec

Comment: @bryanc: You are God. Really are, or at least better than Google Team. Thanks. Please make an answer and I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we tried everything in comments at least we found that should call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after adding items to list view and after when you switch visibility of listview-footer-child too.

Comment: After adding items and after when you switch visibility of listview-footer-child too.